# How to dynamically nest a directive element in-between existing parent and child directive elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angular-directive

**Background:**

I am using a custom CMS where I have limited access to the code base. So, in a few cases I plan to make some DOM manipulations using JavaScript.

**Problem:**

I have a container directive and the container has plain old HTML items, but am not able to mark the items as being directives from the server side. Also, the plain old HTML items contain sub-content that are directives.

**Example:**

Here is the before:

```
DIV[container-directive]

  DIV.some-item-in-html
    DIV[some-directive-in-the-content]


  DIV.some-item-in-html
    DIV[some-directive-in-the-content]

  ...
```

Here is what the DOM should look like afterwards:

```
DIV[container-directive]

  DIV[container-item]       <-- This is what needs to be inserted

    DIV.some-item-in-html
      DIV[some-directive-in-the-content]

  DIV[container-item]       <-- This is what needs to be inserted

    DIV.some-item-in-html
      DIV[some-directive-in-the-content]

  ...
```

**Question:**

Does anyone have suggestions on the best approach to injecting DOM element that are directives in-between a nesting of directives using JavaScript?

**Some thoughts:**

I think manipulate the DOM in advance of the compilation by angular, but I wonder if there is a way to do this within Angular's framework.

Another option is from the container directive's post-linking function, I could wrap the HTML items in directive elements called "container-item" and then $compile the items manually. So, I tried this but I get an error related to the items already having directives inside with transcluded content. Something about the "ngTransclude" being unexpected. I think this is related to the inner directives already having been processed.

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates the problem and the code you tried

Comment: I know what you are asking but I am not really trying to fix broken code. There could be several ways to solve the question above. If so, then my code might not matter if a valid solution is very different. On the other hand if there was only one way to accomplish the question above then my code wouldn't matter either because the answer would have a singular code structure that could be written (presumably with a relatively short amount of code) in the answer, or one who is knowledgeable in the matter could suggestion the best approach without writing code and that would be a valid answer.

Comment: that approach is not really fitting for this site, you mentioned you tried something that didn't work, so post that code. That's usually how it works here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with your first option and manipulate the DOM ahead of angular compilation.

You can do this within a directive that contains the elements that you want to manipulate.

For example:

```
app.directive('body', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
            // find the inner element and wrap it
            $('.some-item-in-html', element).wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Parent directives are always compiled before child directives, so you can change the DOM of the children within the compile property, and not have to worry about recompiling or re-linking directives.

[EDIT]

Thanks to Biagio for the following edit.

This method shouldn't be used with a directive with a template because the element would be assigned to the template and not the child elements.

Another alternative is doing the DOM manipulation in a function that runs at the start of the angular lifecycle.

For example:

```
 app.run(function(){
       // find the inner element and wrap it
      $('.some-item-in-html').wrap('<div     class="container"></div>');
  });
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. In that case I could probably use the compile attribute from the container directive. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes that should work too. Just make sure you manipulate the DOM of the children only.  Using the 'body' as a directive is convenient because everything is a child of body.

Comment: Oh yeah, the container directive uses a template, and so the element provided by the compile attribute is the template and not the contents that would be transcluded. I tried what you suggested and manually inserting the wrapper elements using a parent directive works the way you have written it. Also, simply placing the "pre-processing" DOM manipulation in the module run() function works, too. I am sort of hoping there is another more angular-like option we haven't thought of yet... if that makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense - this method shouldn't be used with a directive with a template or with a directive that uses transclusion.